# Overload method not changing values in object

Tags: java, methods

So I have two overloaded methods in a `main` class which I'm trying to use to set the values of an object. The methods are used from another class but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. When I use a display method it is printing out the original values for `Customer` rather than the new ones set by the method.

```
public class Customer {
    int customerID = 0;
    String name = "Name required";
    String address = "Address required";
    String phoneNumber = "Phone Required";
    String eMail = "email optional";

    public void setCustomerInfo(int ID, String nm, String addr, String phn) {
        int customerID = ID;
        String name = nm;
        String address = addr;
        String phoneNumber = phn;
    }

    public void setCustomerInfo(int ID, String nm, String addr, String phn, String mail) {
        int customerID = ID;
        String name = nm;
        String address = addr;
        String phoneNumber = phn;
        String eMail = mail;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Customer ID: " + customerID);
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Customer Address: " + address);
        System.out.println("Customer Phone Number: " + phoneNumber);
        System.out.println("Customer Email Address: " + eMail);
    }
}
```

-

```
public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        Customer c2 = new Customer();

        c1.setCustomerInfo(1, "Greg", "123 Real Street", "1234-5678");
        c2.setCustomerInfo(2, "Mike", "123 Fake Street", "9876-5432", "RealEmails@Emails.com");

        System.out.println(c1.name);

        c1.display();
        c2.display();
    }
}
```

But the program prints the initial values from the Customer instances:

```
Name required
Customer ID: 0
Customer Name: Name required
Customer Address: Address required
Customer Phone Number: Phone Required
Customer Email Address: email optional
Customer ID: 0
Customer Name: Name required
Customer Address: Address required
Customer Phone Number: Phone Required
Customer Email Address: email optional
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods are assigning values to local variables instead of the class members. Change them to :

```
public void setCustomerInfo(int ID, String nm, String addr, String phn) {

    customerID = ID;
    name = nm;
    address = addr;
    phoneNumber = phn;
}

public void setCustomerInfo(int ID, String nm, String addr, String phn, String mail) {

    customerID = ID;
    name = nm;
    address = addr;
    phoneNumber = phn;
    eMail = mail;
}
```